How to get Android phone IP using python
I'm trying to get the IP of my phone using Python and the flet framework that outputs Android app.  I used socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) but it returns me localhost address in android.
I used socket and platform (didn't work and returned 127.0.0.1)
I want to program give the IP of the device according to the network even without internet access.

It didn't help..

Yes you're right I misread your question.... My apologies

Try this:
import ipaddress
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_address(socket.gethostbyname(hostname))
print(ip_addr)

Gives: 192.168.1.10
Note: This will give you the IP address of your primary network interface.
To get your public ip, use this code:
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://ifconfig.me/ip")
ip_addr = resp.text

print(ip_addr)


socket.gethostname() returns "localhost" in Android, even device connected to network..

yes because it's the default hostname used in most of the android phones which corresponds to 127.0.0.1. You will need to edit your question and tell others which interface ip address you want the code to give.

Thanks a lot. I want the code to give me the IP address of the wifi my phone connected to, or if the computer is connected to the phone's hotpot, give me its IP.

type ifconfig using termux or other terminal on your android phone and share it's complete output with the ip you want the code to give from that output. it's really confusing to tell what you want to achieve here.
